# Points along lines at set elevation intervals

Tags: qgis, intersection, elevation, lines-to-points

I am looking for a way to create points along lines (roads) at set elevation differences (0.5m height differences) using QGIS.

Comment: Well what data do you have? Do you have a DEM? What resolution?

Comment: I am running QGIS 3.2.1. 

I am not using a DEM, I have line strings that have z-values. 

I essentially need to determine points along those lines that differ 0.5m in elevation one after the other.

Comment: OK we still need more info on your data model. Does each line segment have a single z value that represents the entire line? Is each line split at each vertex and have a z value for each vertex in the attribute table?

Answer (score 4):

1. Compute [contour lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#contour) from your elevation raster
2. Intersect your road layer with the contour lines using the [line intersection](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#line-intersections) tool.

[image]